# std::chrono calculate the difference in different ratio

Tags: c++

My title may not be very helpful, I have an std::chrono::nanosecond, but I am asked to serialise and provide the second, and then the nanosecond as different values in a JSON.

So although my struct holds:

```
struct time
{
     ...
     std::chrono::nanoseconds timepoint;
};
```

when asked for seconds, I do

```
uint32_t sec() const
{
     return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(timepoint_).count();
}
```

yet when asked for nanoseconds, I want the resolution in nanoseconds, but without the seconds (only the least significant values?) however, casting in nanoseconds returns both the seconds and the higher resolution.

```
uint64_t nanosec() const
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(timepoint_).count();
}
```

How can I calculate the actual increased resolution (e.g., the nanoseconds without the actual seconds)?

Comment: Try first taking the seconds timepoint (result of the cast before calling `.count()`), and then subtracting it from the actual timepoint. The resulting timepoint should have only the "leftover" nanoseconds.

Comment: Would modding by 1 billion suffice?

Comment: @Xarn I'm a bit confused, could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the seconds using `std::duration_cast` to `std::seconds` and the nanoseconds using modulo operator:

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<T, T> split (std::chrono::duration<T, std::nano> const& duration) {
    using seconds = std::chrono::duration<T>;
    return {std::chrono::duration_cast<seconds>(duration).count(),
            (duration % seconds{1}).count()};
}
```

There is a good example on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4) showing the use of arithmetic operators on `std::chrono::duration` to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: Modulo works sanely on `chrono::duration`? Gonna use that in the future.

Comment: @Xarn It is defined by the standard, so I assume it is meant to work sanely (this is a modulo on two `std::chrono::duration` directly).

Comment: Many thanks for the example. Out of curiosity, you use `modulo` and divide the the nanosecond duration into seconds and split the remainder?

Comment: @Ælex I divide using the cast to `seconds` and compute the remainder using the modulo.

Answer (score 1):

user @Xarn offered the solution:

```
auto sec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(tp);
auto nsec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp);
auto diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(nsec - sec).count();
```

leaves the nanosecond resolution without the seconds.